# How to Move Button Text?

Tags: html, css

Button text by default is centered horizontally and centered vertically.  How do you vertically align the button text to the top?

I've inspected the element and it has 0 padding.

vertical-align: text-top; does not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are more likely to attract more attention and replies to your problem if you create a snippet with your actual code to make it easier for people to respond. Making a working example/fiddle would be even better.

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by flexbox.
First you can add a span inside the button which will contain the text:

```
<button>
  <span>text</span>
</button>
```

And the css will be like:

```
button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; //For vertical alignment [all values: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch]
    justify-content: center; //For horizontal alignment [all values: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly]
}
```

You can experiment for which position you want to show your text.